# Airflow Graph View Not Updated

Tags: airflow

I changed some dependencies between my tasks yesterday for my daily ETL. The new code is correctly shown in the Airflow Code view, and the Gantt also shows things running according to that new code. However, the Graph View still shows the old dependencies. Is there any reason there should be a delay on updating it, or is there anything I need to do, or is something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to hit "refresh" button?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to update?

Comment: @bamdan yes, it updated the next time the ETL ran without me doing anything.

Comment: Was the computer restarted or the web server restarted in between your issue and when it start working?

Comment: No, it was not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart the webserver before the changes will show then restart using

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

This worked for me. People had similar issues and worked for them.

[Airflow "This DAG isnt available in the webserver DagBag object "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560614/airflow-this-dag-isnt-available-in-the-webserver-dagbag-object)