# create airflow dag dynamically looping though a dictionary

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to add airflow dag dynamically looping through the dictionary keys and assigning keys as dag name.

dags are creating fine but i am getting :"This DAG isn't available in the webserver DagBag object. It shows up in this list because the scheduler marked it as active in the metdata database" and its not clickable.

```
def create_dag(dag_id):
    args = build_default_args(config_file)
    dag = DAG(dag_id,schedule_interval='30 11 * * *', default_args=args)
    with dag:
        init_task = BashOperator(
                    task_id='test_init_task',
                    bash_command='echo "task"',
                    dag=dag
                )
        init_task
    return dag

def get_data(**kwargs):
    my_list=[]
    file = open("/home/airflow/gcs/data/test.json")
    data=json.load(file)
    return data

data1 = data()

for dict in data1:
    for pair in dict.items():
        key , value = pair
        print "key",ls_table ,"value",metrics
        dag_id = '{}'.format(key)
        default_args = {'owner': 'airflow',
                    'start_date': datetime(2019, 6, 18)
                    }
        schedule = '@daily'
        globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id)
```

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to create DAGs? Can the same output be achieved by creating tasks inside a DAG?

Comment: check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560614/airflow-this-dag-isnt-available-in-the-webserver-dagbag-object